# cpu max frequency

Tags: 20.04, cpu, cpufreq, frequency, cpupower

I am trying to change my cpu max frequency. I have tried with tlp, cpupower, and the solution in this same forum (the one that goes: for x in /sys/devices/system/cpu/*/cpufreq/; do echo 1700000 | sudo tee $x/scaling_max_freq; done)

None of these have helped me. My frequency range is set from 0.8 to 2.2 GHz. I want to change my max freq. this is the info from cpupower:

```
driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
  hardware limits: 800 MHz - 2.20 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 800 MHz and 2.20 GHz.
                  The governor "powersave" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency: 800 MHz (asserted by call to kernel)
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
```

PLEASE HELP ME! thanks! :)

Comment: please show us your work. Do this: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq` then do this `echo 1700000 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq` then do the first step again, `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq`. Make sure all other stuff like tlp and cpupower and ... is disabled when you do this. I can only help with primatives, and I never ever use that other stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I disabled tlp and other stuff. it still says max freq is 2200000. I was not able to change it. Any other suggestions?

Comment: we need processor model number, kernel version, flavor of Ubuntu 20.04, and the entire outputs for `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/*` and `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/*`. As far as I know what you describe is not possible, so we need to figure out why. And... edit your question showing your work for your above comment.

Comment: Nevermind, I now understand that the base of my processor is 2.2 GHz and that if I want more power I can use the intel turbo. Thanks!